# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer Dependency could not be resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm currently working on an api and need to install this package to use jwt authentication. The only problem is that I can't make it work.
Here goes a picture of the error:
[image]

And here goes the a copy of my project.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Dtos": "1.0.0-*",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.2.0",
    "AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection": "1.1.0",
    "MongoDb": "1.0.0-*",
    "Core.DAL": "1.0.0-*",
    "PusherServer": "4.0.0-rc1",
    "Core.Documents": "1.0.0-*",
    "Core.Entities": "1.0.0-*",
    "Core.Automapper": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.production.json",
      "appsettings.development.json",
      "bundleconfig.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win8-x86": {},
    "win7-x86": {}
  }
}
```

The error dotnet restore throws:

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "C:\Users\Andoni Zubizarreta\Documents\Projects\DeepMarket.vs\restore.dg"
>   C:\Users\Andoni Zubizarreta\Documents\Projects\DeepMarket.vs\restore.dg(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Please let me know if you need something more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I copy and pasted your `project.json` into a new project and got it to build fine. Can you post the result of a `dotnet restore` so that I can see what the error is?

Comment: @A.Bello Thanks for the help. I know it's a strange error, I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by manually running dotnet restore in the package manager console. It seems that my Visual Studio has a problem restoring the packages automatically. Thanks for the help.